# How to enumerate a list of posts?

Tags: pages, list

I've created a page with a list of posts from a specific category. I would like to enumerate this list like this:

- lecture 1: post title 1
- lecture 2: post title 2
- lecture 3: post title 3
- etc.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: So what you basically asking is how to list posts but prefix the titles with Lecure # (where # is a numeric value), right? Would it be safe to assume, the first in the list will naturally be number one, and the second number two, and so on...

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your loop looks like from which you are adding the articles to your list. All you need do is to create a variable to hold your counter somewhere before the while statement in your loop. This could be something like

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
```

Note I am setting the counter to 0. Within the while statement you now enumerate this variable, this will keep on adding one to the counter for every time through the loop.

```
<?php $counter++ ;?>
```

Inside your loop you now use the variable to show the numbers you are interested in. This will give you a one on the first loop, two on the second etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found in the Codex. Simply replace the category number with the one you are using.  I modified it with the counter you requested.

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array('category' => 6, 'offset' => 1, 'numberposts' => -1, 'order' => asc, 'exclude' => '4307,4321');
$myposts = get_posts($args);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($myposts as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
?>
    <div>
        <li class="paginaIndex-temario">Lesson # <?php echo $counter++;?> <a
                href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

HTH

Comment: Hi RXN, I added the 'offset' to the code (everything else is exaclty like your code) but nothing happens. The numbers are not there.

Comment: I've been thinking that I did not explain myself correctly. I already have the list of posts, what I would like to do is to assign, in front of every post title a number progression such as lecture 1: title post 1; lecture 2: title post 2, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Pere, I edited my post with the counter.  I tested this in my machine and it displayed "Lesson # 1 ..., Lesson #2...".  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted my loop to be like the one proposed by RXN, so it is like this:

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'category' => 3, 'offset'=> 1, 'numberposts' => -1, 'order' => asc, 'exclude' => '4307,4321');
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<div>
    <li class="paginaIndex-temario"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

and I introduced a list-style-type:decimal; in the stylesheed. Nevertheless I got a consecutive list of numbers for each post title everywhere but on Explorer (this give me a list of 1.,1.,1.,etc.) so I'm, at best, half way to success.

Any thoughts? I would like to try whith the `<?php $counter = 0; ?>` but I really don't know what to do with it.

Thanks

Comment: How about using `ol` instead of `ul`?